Zeep WSDL Client - schemas website offline
I am trying to use de zeep package and load a WSDL client.
Client('https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl')
The client url is working fine but I received an error during the Client instantiation. It seems that the schemas website that it uses is offline. Is there a workaround?
Error message:
404 Client Error: Site Not Found for url: https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
